# How to start a php session() and access $_SESSION in CakePHP 3.x?

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I see from the CakePHP 3.2 documentation that to configure a session I need to use write(), so I tried that in my controller like this:

```
use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Core\Configure;

class RatingsController extends AppController
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
        Configure::write('Session', ['defaults' => 'php']);
   }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to set up a $_SESSION array if executed in my controller.

I thought I had a workaround by setting up Auth, and thereby was able to access $_SESSION, but then when I open the controller by adding `$this->Auth->allow();` to the init above, the session variable no longer exists.

Where do I need to configure Cake to start a session?

Comment: Why do you want to access `$_SESSION` in the first place? You shouldn't access any superglobals directly when using CakePHP!

Comment: I need a persistent variable. I can use $this->request->session()->read() just fine, if $_SESSION was created by cake.

Comment: This is covered in the docs: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html

Comment: My question was more like why you would want to access `$_SESSION` _directly_ (not why you want to use sessions at all), as this is what your questions sounds like as it stands.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. Answer section solves my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CakePHP binds sessions to the Request, e.g. set a value to a key in your Controller:

```
$this->request->session()->write('defaults', 'php')
```

Then, e.g. in your Template read the Session by key:

```
$this->request->session()->read('defaults')
```